# Not seeing the effects of action on a vector's last element via a reference

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

It seems I don't fully understand how exactly C++ references work. Trying to run following snippet:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> test{1,2,3};
    int& ref = test.back();
    auto lambda = [&ref, &test](){
        std::cout << "inside lambda " << ref << std::endl;
        ref += 1;
        for (auto&v : test) { std::cout << v << " "; }
    };

    lambda(); lambda(); lambda();
    test.push_back(5);
    lambda(); lambda(); lambda();
}
```

And got this result:

```
inside lambda 3                                                                                                                                                                       
1 2 4                                                                                                                                                                                 
inside lambda 4                                                                                                                                                                       
1 2 5                                                                                                                                                                                 
inside lambda 5                                                                                                                                                                       
1 2 6                                                                                                                                                                                 
inside lambda 6                                                                                                                                                                       
1 2 6 5                                                                                                                                                                               
inside lambda 7                                                                                                                                                                       
1 2 6 5                                                                                                                                                                               
inside lambda 8                                                                                                                                                                       
1 2 6 5
```

Why after `push_back` is done, none of vector elements is incremented?
And where `ref` points to from this moment?

Comment: If the vector needs to reallocate its data storage, all iterators and pointer and references to elements become invalidated.

Comment: Death by reallocation. The vector's content moved away, but the reference stayed and became dangling.

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with lambdas, you would have gotten the same thing without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At start, `ref` references the third element of the storage of `test`. After pushing back a new element it happens that the `vector` reallocated its storage, so that the old `ref` element is no more valid. Your code leads to **undefined behaviour**.